# Bokeh initial x axis zoom range and allow full zoom out on x axis with y_range bound

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

With the following I can set an initial x axis zoom range of the last 4 hours. Ideally I wish to use the wheel zoom to scroll out on the x axis only and view the whole plot but remain bound on the y axis by the range set. The following does not allow this and setting either of the following also does not:

```
y_range=DataRange1d(0, y_max, bounds="auto")
y_range=DataRange1d(0, y_max) # i.e. bounds=None as per docs
```

Can anyone assist in how I can allow an initial view on the x axis, allow zoom out on the x axis, but set bounds on the y axis such that the user cannot zoom out beyond the plot boundaries of min y=0 and (in the example) max y=8?

Example code with bounds statically set on y axis as per docs [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/ranges.html#bokeh.models.ranges.DataRange1d.bounds):

```
import pandas as pandas
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataRange1d, Range1d

output_file('stackoverflowq.html')

list1 = [['2020-12-03 09:20:03.175453','5'],['2020-12-04 09:20:03.175453','7'],['2020-12-05 09:20:03.175453','3'],['2020-12-05 09:30:03.175453','4'],['2020-12-05 09:40:03.175453','5'],['2020-12-05 09:50:03.175453','6'],['2020-12-05 10:00:03.175453','4'],['2020-12-05 10:10:03.175453','1'],['2020-12-05 10:20:03.175453','2'],['2020-12-05 10:30:03.175453','8'],['2020-12-05 10:40:03.175453','2'],['2021-01-03 09:20:03.175453','5'],['2021-01-04 09:20:03.175453','7'],['2021-01-05 09:20:03.175453','3'],['2021-01-20 09:30:03.175453','4'],['2021-01-21 01:40:03.175453','5'],['2021-01-21 02:50:03.175453','6'],['2021-01-21 06:00:03.175453','4'],['2021-01-21 07:10:03.175453','1'],['2021-01-21 08:20:03.175453','2'],['2021-01-21 09:30:03.175453','8'],['2021-01-21 10:40:03.175453','2']]

cols = ['DateTime','vals']
df = pandas.DataFrame(list1,columns=cols)
df['DateTime'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
df = df.set_index('DateTime')

y_max = int(df.vals.unique().max())*1.2

x_max = df.index.unique().max()
x_min = x_max - pandas.Timedelta('4h')

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", y_range=DataRange1d(0, y_max, bounds=(0, y_max)), x_range=(x_min, x_max))

p.line(x='DateTime', y='vals', color='blue', source=df)

p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Date Time'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'vals'

show(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have simply to change the wheel zoom tool. Use `tools='xwheel_zoom'`.

**Example**
Please use my minimal example and give me some feedback if you have still this issue.

```
import pandas as pd # version 1.1.4
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show # version 2.2.3
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DataRange1d, Range1d
output_notebook()
date_times = pd.Timestamp.now()
x_max = date_times
x_min = date_times - pd.Timedelta('4h')
x = [x_max - pd.Timedelta(f'{t}h') for t in range(5,0,-1)]
y = [2, 5, 8, 2, 7]

other_tools = "pan, box_zoom, save, reset, help,"
p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools="xwheel_zoom,"+other_tools, x_range=(x_min,x_max))
p.circle(x, y, size=10)
show(p)
```

| **Inital zoom** | **Zoomed Out with `wheel_zoom`** | **Zoomed Out with `xwheel_zoom`** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: inital zoom] | [image: zoomed out] | [image: zoomed out xwheel_zoom] |
|  | [image: selection bar] | You have to select the wheel zoom tool by mouse click. |

Comment: Hi mosc9575, thanks for coming back to me quickly. I've tested your example and get the desired output I described (though I actually want a max_interval/bounds too so the maximum zoom out is the full plot as opposed to blank space). This said...the bigger issue is that my code doesn't do what yours does, I'll create a minimal example tomorrow and confirm back!

Comment: Ok I've fixed the issue but opened up another. I was setting p = figure(y_range=DataRange1d(0, max, bounds="auto")) too where max was the maximum y plot value calculated across the entire data range, not just the x_range used for the initial zoom.
Removing bounds="auto", i.e. seeing the default of None applied, allows me to zoom out of the initial x_range view and see the whole dataset.
However, when I then zoom out I then lose my Y bounds as the x_range increases. Ideally I still want to stop the user from zoom below the minimum and maximum y values but still allow the x_range to change.

Comment: I've updated the question with a full example of the "new" problem following identification of the first.

Comment: I got it. Please check my answer.

Comment: Hi mosc9575, I've not had chance to test it but having read a bit around xwheel_zoom it sounds like that'll do the trick! Thank you very much! I'll test it tomorrow to confirm for certain!

Comment: mosc9575 - that works perfectly thank you! Now having read around a bit more I might want to play with the wheel panning tool or controlling the wheel zoom's dimension properties instead but this works as I wished. Thanks very much for your help and testing, appreciate it! And sorry, my reputation isn't high enough to mark your answer as correct...

Comment: You are welcome. Maybe you can mark it, when your reputation raises.

Comment: Just me being silly and trying to upvote as opposed to mark, done now!